# How to add a tool model onto the robot model which can be generated in the moveit

Tags: ros, moveit, integration, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,
I have downloaded the UR10 robot description(including the urdf and other components) in the ROS without a tool on the end effector. Now i have a mechanical mechanism which has been exported as a URDF in Solidworks. The problem is how can i add the mechanical mechanism as a tool on the robot end effector and open the entire model in the RVIZ? Do you have any tutorial about it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271839/how-to-add-a-tool-model-onto-the-robot-model-which-can-be-generated-in-the-moveit/) by [pdmike](https://answers.ros.org/users/32007/pdmike/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-09-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andymcevoy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1860/andymcevoy/) on 2017-09-29**:
do you just need to combine the URDF files? Your question makes it sound like you have a URDF of the UR10 and a URDF file of the end effector? Or do you just have the STL files from SW and need to create a URDF for the end effector?

**Comment by [pdmike](https://answers.ros.org/users/32007/pdmike/) on 2017-09-30**:
Thanks for your reply. I have both URDF of UR10 and end effector. I want to combine them. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I typically use [XACRO](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro) to combine arms and grippers.

for example:

```
<robot name="myrobot" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">

<!-- myrobot urdf file -->
<xacro:include filename="$(find mypackage)/urdf/myrobotarm_no_end_effectors.urdf"/>

<!-- add any joints/links required to connect the two -->

<xacro:include filename="$(find mypackage)/urdf/an_end_effector.urdf.xacro" />

</robot>
```

I usually write the end effector as an xacro macro so that I can attach it to either a right or left arm or launch it standalone to trouble shoot the URDF file if need be.

Hope that helps.

---

Originally posted by [andymcevoy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1860/andymcevoy/) with karma: 46 on 2017-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pdmike](https://answers.ros.org/users/32007/pdmike/) on 2017-10-16**:
Thank you. The answer has helped me a lot

**Comment by [andymcevoy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1860/andymcevoy/) on 2017-10-17**:
@pdmike since you didn't accept, can I assume there's some aspect of this you're still having trouble with?

**Comment by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on 2018-07-20**:
@andymcevoy your answer helped me a lot.

Although the base packages of the robots can be remained untouched, I still find it very inconvenient that you need to create a new moveit package for every single tool configuration of your endeffector.

I am wondering If there is a more elegant way to be a